# Ignore "defaultlib"-directives in specific .lib-file

Tags: visual-c++, static-linking

I'm trying to build a Win32 application, which is to use a 3rd party .lib. I get errors that "LIBC" is not found (I'm using Visual C++ 2010 express), and i've tracked this reference to the 3rd party lib. Adding "/NODEFAULTLIB" solves the reference to LIBC, but in turn provides a plethora of missing symbols (of course). 
I know that LIBC is single-threaded, and can give all sorts of head-aches, but right now i'm just trying to get a succesful link.

Best regards,
Soren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, I fixed it!

It seems I just had to open my eyes, going to:
Project->Properties->Linker->Input

I just needed to add "libc" to the "Ignore Specific Default Libraries", instead of just enabling "Ignore All Default Libraries".

The thing even works (just did a quick run). There may of course be hidden errors due to the multithreaded version of standard C libraries being used, but so far so good!

Answer (score 2):

It is just a hint to the linker, injected with #pragma comment(lib, "libc.lib").  The `/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib` linker option extinguishes it again.  If you now get linker errors then you actually *do* need to link to libc.lib explicitly.

Which is otherwise pretty unlikely to come to a good end, that library dates from the previous century.  Modern versions of VS use libcmt.lib, there is no single-threaded version of the CRT anymore.  So if this libc.lib reference came from a .lib or .obj that was compiled in the previous century then you have a bigger problem.  The compiler header files have changed too much to still allow that to work.

Not posting the linker errors prevents a better answer.

Comment: Yes I get all that, the question is: Can I use the current C-library for that old lib? It IS the standard C library, so how could the interface have changed?

Comment: Hans, thank you for answering. I think maybe my frustration with the old lib was shining through my previous comment. I'm aware that the issue is potentially bad, but I have my reasons to just try to get the thing linking....

Comment: The standard C library is only source compatible, not binary compatible.  With the strong assumption that you can always recompile from source.  If you can't then it will be the linker that rubs your nose into it.  Again, nothing useful can be said beyond this if you refuse to post the linker errors you see.

Comment: Thank you Hans, As Ive pointed out in my own answer, the question I was really asking, and by sheer luck managed to solve my self was: Ignore references to a specific default library. Thank you for taking time to try and answer my question, and have a nice weekend!